# Changing buttons' texts on another activities causes error (Unfortunately appname has Stopped)

Tags: android

I have an android project on eclipse , so I making localization for it (for both Arabic and English users).

The problem simply is that  when I press a button (English or Arabic button) to  change buttons' texts on that activities other than the current activity (MainActivity) I get the error:-

Unfortunately , appname has stopped.

But when I run the application without changing these Buttons' texts (Only changing  MainActivity buttons' texts from language to language) there is no errors and the application works fine.

This the **MainActivity.java** (Observe that I put  ZAD_ISLAMI_button as an instance of ZAD_ISLAMI_BUTTON which itself a button from another activity).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
        private Button English,Arabic,life_pls,Top_Team ,exit,MobiLink_button,
                Amro_Khaled ,Short_SMS_button ,ZAD_ISLAMI_button;
        private Locale myLocale;
        public void changeLang(String lang)
        {
                if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        return;
                myLocale = new Locale(lang);
                saveLocale(lang);
                Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
                android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
                config.locale = myLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                updateTexts();
        }
        public void saveLocale(String lang)
        {
                String langPref = "Language";
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(langPref, lang);
                editor.commit();
        }

        public void loadLocale()
        {
                String langPref = "Language";
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
                changeLang(language);
        }
        private void updateTexts()
        {

                English.setText(R.string.English);
                Arabic.setText(R.string.Arabnas);
                life_pls.setText(R.string.Life_Plus_Button);
                Top_Team.setText(R.string.Top_Team_Button);
                Zad_button.setText(R.string.Zad_Button);
                Amro_Khaled.setText(R.string.Amro_Khaled_Button);
                Short_SMS_button.setText(R.string.Short_SMS_Button);
                //The problem here in ZAD_ISLAMI_button.
                ZAD_ISLAMI_button.setText(R.string.ZAD_ISLAMI_BUTTON);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                this.English= (Button)findViewById(R.id.English);
                this.Arabic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Arabics);
                this.life_pls = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Life_Plus_Button);
                this.Top_Team =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Top_Team_Button);
                this.Amro_Khaled =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Amro_Khaled_Button);
                this.ZAD_ISLAMI_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ZAD_ISLAMI_BUTTON);
                Button  english = (Button) findViewById(R.id.English);
                english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                String lang = "en";
                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                        case R.id.English:
                                                lang = "en";
                                                break;
                                        case R.id.Arabics:
                                                lang = "ar";
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                }
                                changeLang(lang);
                        }
                });
                Button  Arabic= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Arabics);
                Arabic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                String lang = "ar";
                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                        case R.id.English:
                                                lang = "en";
                                                break;
                                        case R.id.Arabics:
                                                lang = "ar";
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                }
                                changeLang(lang);
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

**activity_main.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MobiLink_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Short_SMS_Button "
        android:text="@string/MobiLink_Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Short_SMS_Button "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Amro_Khaled_Button"
        android:text="@string/Short_SMS_Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Zad_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Amro_Khaled_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/Zad_Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Top_Team_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Zad_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/Top_Team_Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Life_Plus_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Top_Team_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/Life_Plus_Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/application_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/English"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="بالانجليزي" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/English"
        android:text="@string/exit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Arabics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="بالعربية" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Amro_Khaled_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Amro_Khaled_Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `ZAD_ISLAMI_BUTTON` Button is not defined in XML. Are you sure `ZAD_ISLAMI_BUTTON` is not null?

Comment: You would need to start the second activity in order to change a buttons text in it.

Comment: @KalpeshPatel  ZAD_ISLAMI_BUTTON is defined in another XML file(another screen).

Comment: @MJ93 Would I need to start all activities to change their buttons' texts without displaying their xml files is this the best solution?

Comment: you need to call change button text from onCreate of each activity, so that part of code will be run only when that particular activity is created. Store user selected language setting from first activity, in some preference and set button text in subsequent activity based on that.

Comment: You can not access View which is defined in another XML file. until and unless it is attached to view hierarchy of that activity.

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun Yes, take a look at Kaustuv's comment also.